# adding event listeners in Javascript is doubling my (simple) maths

Tags: javascript, html

I will attempt to be as concise as possible, but am out of my depth (i should be in the baby pool :)

I'm trying to make a simple website for my son that presents a random sentence with a blank where an adverb should be. The user then has to guess which of the three randomised words presented below is an adverb. I have then tried to implement a scoring system which is where my problem lies.

I had it working OK, when the buttons were static, but since randomising and adding event listeners to the answer buttons it is adding two to the score instead of one. The problem code is towards the bottom (//add event listeners to buttons)

One further problem is that when someone answers the first question incorrectly my code says they have 'undefined correct answers'. I can't get that to say '0 correct answers'

````
  <head>
    <title>Adverb Kings</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Adverb Kings</h1>

    <div id="sentence"></div>

    <div>
      <button type="button" onclick="right()"></button>
      <button type="button" onclick="wrong()"></button>
      <button type="button" onclick="wrong()"></button>
        
        <div id="result"></div>
      <div id="correct"></div>
      <div id="attempted"></div>
      

    </div>
    
    <script>
//define right functions
function right() {
    correctAlert();
    correctAnswer();
    answersAttempted();
    }
//define wrong functions
function wrong() {
    incorrectAlert();
    answersAttempted();
    }
//alert correct 
function correctAlert() {
    var element = document.getElementById("result");
    element.classList.add("correct");
    element.innerHTML = "Correct";
    }
        
//alert incorrect
function incorrectAlert() {
    var element = document.getElementById("result");
    element.classList.add("incorrect");
    element.innerHTML = "Incorrect, try again.";
    }
    
//tracking correct answers
function correctAnswer() {
    
        if (sessionStorage.correct) {sessionStorage.correct = Number(sessionStorage.correct)+1;
} else {
      sessionStorage.correct = 1;
    }
     
}
   
//tracking attempted questions count
function answersAttempted() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (sessionStorage.attempts) {
      sessionStorage.attempts = Number(sessionStorage.attempts)+1;
    } else {
      sessionStorage.attempts = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("attempted").innerHTML = "You have attempted " + sessionStorage.attempts + " question(s) in this session and got " + sessionStorage.correct + " correct" ;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("attempted").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
         
//create sentence array
var sentence;
      sentence = ['The people _______ went crazy about the new game options', 'The man _______ slipped his hands around his desk handle', 'He _______ typed a new password for his school account'];

      //randomise sentence array
      var el = document.getElementById('sentence');
      el.textContent = sentence[Math.floor(Math.random() * sentence.length)];

      //set order of words in order to randomise
      var orders = [0, 1, 2];
      shuffle(orders);
      
      //add event listeners to buttons
      var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
      buttons[orders[0]].addEventListener('click', right);
      buttons[orders[1]].addEventListener('click', wrong);
      buttons[orders[2]].addEventListener('click', wrong);
      
      //create and randomise adverb array
      var adverbs = ['slowly', 'quickly', 'insanely'];
      buttons[orders[0]].textContent = adverbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * adverbs.length)];

      //create and randomise other words
      var other1 = ['burger', 'insane', 'ugly'];
      buttons[orders[1]].textContent = other1[Math.floor(Math.random() * other1.length)];
      var other2 = ['sausage', 'fist', 'gun'];
      buttons[orders[2]].textContent = other2[Math.floor(Math.random() * other2.length)];
      
      //shuffle position of adverb
      function shuffle(array) {
        array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
      }

    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: So you have an inline event handler calling the method and one added with addEventListener and you wonder why it is called twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the event listeners both in the HTML and JS.

Remove the onclick="..." part of the buttons in the HTML and all should be good.

To stop the number being undefined, set sessionStorage.correct to 0 before you call any functions:

```
<script>
    sessionStorage.correct = 0;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added event listener twice on in HTML and one in js code due to which it is hitting twice.
regarding the undefined value, when hitting incorrect first-time session storage is not initialized due to which it is showing undefined. please check below js code where I have commented the js event listener and initialize the sessionstorage.correct and now it is working fine.

**code**

```
                                //define right functions
                                function right() {
                                    
                                    correctAlert();
                                    correctAnswer();
                                    answersAttempted();
                                    }
                                //define wrong functions
                                function wrong() {
                                    incorrectAlert();
                                    answersAttempted();
                                    }
                                //alert correct 
                                function correctAlert() {
                                    var element = document.getElementById("result");
                                    element.classList.add("correct");
                                    element.innerHTML = "Correct";
                                    }
                                        
                                //alert incorrect
                                function incorrectAlert() {
                                    var element = document.getElementById("result");
                                    element.classList.add("incorrect");
                                    element.innerHTML = "Incorrect, try again.";
                                  
                                    }
                                    
                                //tracking correct answers
                                function correctAnswer() {
                                    
                                        if (sessionStorage.correct) {sessionStorage.correct = Number(sessionStorage.correct)+1;
                                         
                                            
                                } else {
                                    sessionStorage.correct = 1;
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                
                                //tracking attempted questions count
                                function answersAttempted() {
                                if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
                                    if (sessionStorage.attempts) {
                                    sessionStorage.attempts = Number(sessionStorage.attempts)+1;
                                    
                                    } else {
                                    sessionStorage.attempts = 1;
                               
                                    }
                                    // initializing sessionStorage.correct
                                    if(!sessionStorage.correct) {
                                        sessionStorage.correct=0;
                                    }
                                    document.getElementById("attempted").innerHTML = "You have attempted " + sessionStorage.attempts + " question(s) in this session and got " + sessionStorage.correct + " correct" ;
                                } else {
                                    document.getElementById("attempted").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
                                }
                                }
                                        
                                //create sentence array
                                var sentence;
                                    sentence = ['The people _______ went crazy about the new game options', 'The man _______ slipped his hands around his desk handle', 'He _______ typed a new password for his school account'];
                                
                                    //randomise sentence array
                                    var el = document.getElementById('sentence');
                                    el.textContent = sentence[Math.floor(Math.random() * sentence.length)];
                                
                                    //set order of words in order to randomise
                                    var orders = [0, 1, 2];
                                    shuffle(orders);
                                    
                                    //add event listeners to buttons
                                    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
                                    //  buttons[orders[0]].addEventListener('click', right);
                                    // buttons[orders[1]].addEventListener('click', wrong);
                                    // buttons[orders[2]].addEventListener('click', wrong);
                                    
                                    //create and randomise adverb array
                                    var adverbs = ['slowly', 'quickly', 'insanely'];
                                    buttons[orders[0]].textContent = adverbs[Math.floor(Math.random() * adverbs.length)];
                                
                                    //create and randomise other words
                                    var other1 = ['burger', 'insane', 'ugly'];
                                    buttons[orders[1]].textContent = other1[Math.floor(Math.random() * other1.length)];
                                    var other2 = ['sausage', 'fist', 'gun'];
                                    buttons[orders[2]].textContent = other2[Math.floor(Math.random() * other2.length)];
                                    
                                    //shuffle position of adverb
                                    function shuffle(array) {
                                        array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
                                    }
```